# How to rewrite this for python 3

Tags: python

How to rewrite this for Python 3?

```
for ch in "WELCOME TO EARTH!".center(35):
    print ch,
```

It should print like this:

```
                       W E L C O M E   T O   E A R T H!
```

I tried just putting brackets around like this but it didn't work:

```
for ch in "WELCOME TO EARTH!".center(35):
    print (ch,)
```

Comment: `2to3 file.py -w`

Comment: Why just not to `print("WELCOME TO EARTH!".center(35))`? @Colin's answer is perfect though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for ch in "WELCOME TO EARTH!".center(35):
    print(ch, end='')
```

You can read about the `end` argument [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print).